# Generate Flex SOAP client using maven

Tags: apache-flex, soap, maven, jax-ws

I have a java server side project which contains JAX-WS web-services (using JavaEE 6 and the `@WebService` annotation).

Is there some kind of plugin that would allow me to generate Flex client stubs during my maven build ?

I have taken a look at [enunciate](http://enunciate.codehaus.org/), but it seems to generate only AMF client.

I've also tried to look at [GraniteDS](http://www.graniteds.org/confluence/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=229378), but their doc seems a little opaque to me.

Notice my Flex project is compiled using flexmojos, which contains a flexmojos:generate mojo that should be able to generate domain object (however I don't understand how to say it to use domain classes from ANOTHER project, and not from a different folder).

So, is there any maven plugin that would allow the kind of feature described in [this Adobe page](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/data_access_3.html#193910) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well most solutions use the WebServices WSDL description and generate stuff from that. 
I documented this process in [my Wiki](https://dev.c-ware.de/confluence/display/PUBLIC/Setting+up+Flex+to+communicate+with+Apache+CXF+web+service+using+Aegis+databinding). Don't be confused about the CXF Part, just have a look at the "Seting Flex up as Web Service client" part. When I did this, I used the code generation features of Flash Builder to generate the code and to work with that code.

I know this is not the cleanest way to do it, but it worked then (about 2 Years ago). Things like [wsld2as](http://osflash.org/wsdl2as) weren't available then ... perhaps you should have a look at that.

Comment: Well, in my case, as Glassfish generates the WSDL at deployment time, i don't have it and want to directly map Java service classes to Flex ones. In that case, I don't consider the code generation (outside of the build process) to be the most efficient way, as it allows unsynchronized client to server code.

Comment: Well I never said it was the cleanest way to go ;-) It was just one that did work and then there were no other options without doing everything yourself. Since then I have completely switched over from SOAP communication to AMF communication. Using Graniteds in my build and using customized templates for BlazeDS. I even commited a patch to flexmojos recently that allows to share templates throughout multiple modules (will propably be a part of 4.0-RC2 or 4.0-Final).